# How to change the color of XML elements in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, color-scheme

I have imported a theme, and I have noticed that the color of the value for a key in `app.config` has not been changed:

[image]

Is there any way of editing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the XMLAttributeValue setting.

```
Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts And Colors -> (Text Editor set) XMLAttributeValue
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, but it doesn't work as i just said to Gregjer before.

Comment: Uhm, the only thing that comes to mind is Visual Studio version. I was trying it with VS2012, let me test with VS2010

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask. Have you changed XMLAttributeValue or XAMLAttributeValue? The right one is XMLAttributeValue. (not the XAML one)

Comment: The one thing that I really don't understand is why they (MS) localize these values... It is a nightmare to find the correct ones from english to my locale. (Sorry for the rant but I have to say it loud)

Comment: Thanks Steve. I changed the XMLAttributeValue and nothing happens. As I said before, it changes the value but not the Key name in fact.
"<add key="Element" value="2013"/>" it changes the color of  "2013", not "Element"

Comment: Sorry, but also VS2010 applies the XMLValueAttribute color to both the key and value literal text in a appSettings section. I have no idea what's happening on your side. I would try to check if this happens also with a different theme (you could find many to test at [studiostyl.es](http://studiostyl.es))

Comment: Thanks, i will try, i do not understand why this literal text is still in dark blue...

Comment: Everything works correctly ... VSCommands Override the VS Color Settings ... Mea Culpa. Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: Glad to be of help. See you again on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Go to

> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors

and find there

> Show Settings For -> Text Editor
>
> Display Items -> XML Attribute Value
>
> Item Foreground -> {choose color you prefer}

Comment: Thanks Gregjer. I try this but it doesn't work in fact.
For example, the value affected by this color is : "<add key="Element" value="2013"/>" is "2013", not "Element", and that's the major problem.

Comment: Hmm it works for me, maybe it has something to do with your theme, you could try restarting VS as well

Comment: Everything works correctly ... VSCommands Override the VS Color Settings ... Mea Culpa. Thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is running into this issue, it is not because of the Visual Studio settings. It is because of the VSCommands extension. I disabled the extension and Visual Studio took control back of the color settings. Very poor behavior for an extension to override color control, if you ask me. Changing colors when requested is expected, overriding the control is not!